# How to highlight the first item in a RecyclerView and keep only that itemView selected selected?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So, the problem is that I want to select the first interview in a RecyclerView and highlight it. This is fairly simple for me, however, the minute I scroll-down other itemViews are selected. I am using position to say, hey highlight position 0. How can it hold the itemView to stay selected and not select any other ItemViews?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

        if(position == 0){
            holder.songAuthor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.songTitle.setText("Song Title: " + itemList.get(position).getSongTitle());
            holder.songYear.setText("Song Year: " + itemList.get(position).getSongYear());
            holder.songAuthor.setText("Song Author: " + itemList.get(position).getSongAuthor());

        } else {

            holder.songTitle.setText("Song Title: " + itemList.get(position).getSongTitle());
            holder.songYear.setText("Song Year: " + itemList.get(position).getSongYear());
            holder.songAuthor.setText("Song Author: " + itemList.get(position).getSongAuthor());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your implementation?

Comment: I forgot to override the getItemViewType method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point of `RecyclerView` is that it recycles views - that means that the same ViewHolder will be reused multiple times for other rows that share the same view type.

This means that you must make sure that your `onBindViewHolder` completely resets the ViewHolder to the correct state. In your case, your `else` needs to call `holder.songAuthor.setBackgroundColor()` with whatever your default color is, ensuring that the blue background is reset.

Comment: Thanks to this it works, I am still learning so thank you for the well-put answer.

Comment: Glad to help! It's really helpful if you hit the check box next to the answer to accept the answer, removing this question from the list of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to this all i had to do is to overside this method
`@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }`

Comment: This is a really, really bad idea since it means that the RecyclerView cannot recycle any Views - it *always* needs to call `onCreateViewHolder` for every row since, in its mind, every row is a completely different layout (since they each have a different view type).

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that I wasn't resting my background.